# billboard not rendered

Tags: uv, particles

I am trying to achieve a snow effect with billboard particles, everything is fine until I render the scene where my flakes don't appear.
I understand billboard UV are automatically generated but couldn't sort my problem.
The UVmap slot uses the unwrapped emitter plane (I though it would sort the situation but it obviously doesn't) as the Normal and time index UV.
Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: Cycles does not support billboard particles as far as I know. Replace the billboards with objects (simple planes will suffice): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqBIAE8A-4k